# variable inside ng-model does not work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a directive but before creating a directive I am stuck at a simpler task. I can't make this work for some reason.

```
<div ng-controller="NgModelTraining">
    <input type="text" ng-model="{{dynamic}}" name="{{dynamic}}" required> {{select}}
</div>

(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('NgModelTraining', NgModelTraining);

    /* @ngInject */
    function NgModelTraining ($scope) {
        $scope.dynamic = 'select';
    }

})();
```

I get error when I want to try to set the ng-model value dynamically. How can I handle this?

In other words I am trying to set the ng-model='select', dynamically.

Comment: If you create a directive, you can to inform dynamically the model attribute

Comment: I see that there is no selected answer after more than 7 months, did you solve your problem? I am currently having somewhat the same issue, so i am wondering how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use expression syntax.  Use a String literal.  And no need to specify the value inside the tag:

```
<div ng-controller="NgModelTraining">
    <input type="text" ng-model="dynamic" name="{{dynamic}}" required>
</div>
```

Comment: That is not what I mean, if I leave out the brackets it is the same as saying ng-model="dynamic", and set an initial value of dynamic to select in the controller, that is not what I ment. I ment set ng-model="selelect", because   $scope.dynamic = 'select'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have missed to inject `$scope` with the `NgModelTraining`. Please try by modify your code as below

```
 var NgModelTraining = function ($scope) {
    $scope.dynamic = 'select';
 }
 NgModelTraining.$inject = ["$scope"];
```

And also modify the `ng-model` value as `string` instead of expression as sma suggested.

**Edit**

Actually i don`t know your case but we can use the below way to change the`ng-model` dynamically, give a try.

```
$scope.dynamic = { 
   value1:[...],
   value2: [....] 
 }
$scope.value = "value1" //default value.
```

Now the template will be as follow

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dynamic[value]">
```

If the above one is not helpfull please tell ur scenario.

Comment: I don't need to inject because I am not minifying, and even if I did that is taken care of.

Comment: Could u tell the case in which u want to change the `ng-model` value?